# Is there a way to have custom SQL query on top of JPA repository to have BULK UPSERTS?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, upsert, snowflake-schema

I have a snowflake database and it doesn't support unique constraint enforcement (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constraints-overview.html).

I'm planning to have a method on JPA repository with a custom SQL query to check for duplicates before inserting to the table.

Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENTS")
public class Students {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "ID", columnDefinition = "serial")
  @GenericGenerator(name = "id_generator", strategy = "increment")
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "id_generator")
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "NAME")
  private String studentName;

}
```

Snowflake create table query

```
CREATE table STUDENTS(
    id int identity(1,1) primary key,
    name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE(name)
);
```

Repository

```
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Students, Long> {

//
@Query(value = "???", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Student> bulkUpsertStudents(List<Student> students);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to overcome this using the below approach but need to verify the performance of the queries.

1. Repository saveAll() method to save all the entities.
2. Using the custom nativeQuery as below

   ```
      INSERT OVERWRITE INTO STUDENTS
      WITH CTE AS(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY ID) AS RNO, ID, NAME FROM STUDENTS)
      SELECT ID, NAME FROM CTE WHERE RNO = 1;
   ```

Example code :

```
import static io.vavr.collection.List.ofAll;
import static io.vavr.control.Option.of;
import static java.util.function.Predicate.not;

 public Validation<ValidationError, List<Students>> saveAll(List<String> students) {
    return of(students)
        .filter(not(List::isEmpty))
        .map(this::mapToEntities) // maps the list to list of database entities
        .map(repository::saveAll) // save all
        .toValidation(ERROR_SAVING_STUDENTS) // vavr validation in case of error
        .peek(x -> repository.purgeStudents()) // purging to remove duplicates
        .toValidation(ERROR_PURGING_STUDENTS);
  }
```

This issue is only due to snowflake's incapability to check uniqueness.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `SELECT` query to check for duplicate values in the `name` column before inserting a new record into the table. For example:

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM STUDENTS WHERE name = :name", nativeQuery = true)
List<Student> findByName(@Param("name") String name);
```

This method will return a list of `Student` records with the specified `name` value. If the list is empty, it means that there are no records with that `name` value, and you can safely insert a new record with that `name` value.

```java
List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();
for (Student student : students) {
    List<Student> existingStudents = studentRepository.findByName(student.getName());
    if (existingStudents.isEmpty()) {
        studentsToInsert.add(student);
    }
}
studentRepository.bulkUpsertStudents(studentList)
```

#### EDIT

If the above solution doesn't work. You can use the `MERGE` statement to update existing records in the table if the data has changed. For example, if you want to update the name of a `Student` if it has changed, you can use the following `MERGE` statement:

```java
@Query(value = "MERGE INTO students t USING (SELECT :name AS name, :newName AS newName) s
ON t.name = s.name 
WHEN MATCHED AND t.name <> s.newName THEN UPDATE SET t.name = s.newName
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (name) VALUES (s.name)", nativeQuery = true)
List<Student> bulkUpsertStudents(List<Student> students);
```

This query will update the name of each `Student` in the `students` list if it has changed, and if a conflict occurs, it will not insert a new record. This will ensure that only unique name values are inserted into the table, without having to perform a separate query for each record.

Comment: This will fire select query for each of the record to the database. Imagining if there is 1000 student records, 1000 queries are fired. I was thinking if there is a `insert on conflict`  kind of support

Comment: Getting this error : object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing on the second approach

Comment: Ok I understand I have updated the code can you check now?

Comment: ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING; is not supported by snowflake I was looking for something similar to this